# Is there a good way to submit jobs to a cluster using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, distributed, cluster-computing

Is there a good tool out there to do this on a Linux machine using the bash shell? All I need is to issue different commands on a set of nodes in a cluster and when one of them is done with the job, I'd like to submit another one. Something very similar to what Hadoop can do. I would be interested in knowing the status of the job as well but even otherwise is fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Programs like Sun Grid Engine and Mosix will let you submit all of your jobs at once and will automatically load balance them (meaning it will queue them up so that only the right number are running on a given node at a time).

I've had good experiences with these in scientific computing (on Linux with bash) and highly recommend either.

Comment: Oh... might seem a little odd but can I use them without root privileges? I mean install that on a per user basis?

Comment: That's a good question-- not that I know of. But once you get them on, they're really nice to have.

Comment: I see... +1 for that... Thank You. I will open a support ticket with out admin... In the mean time, I really would love something that is a little portable in the sense that I can install and play around with...

Answer (score 1):

There's also parbash (Parallel Bash):

http://code.google.com/p/parbash/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use mounted NFS/SMB partition and write some scripts yourself.